# How to draw lines connecting pair-wise points above dodging bars in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, grouping

I think the question is sufficiently complex that a code example will help:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
  Subgroup = c("A.1", "A.2", "A.1", "A.2", "B.1", "B.2"),
  Value = c(10, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12),
  Pair = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
)

dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.9)
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = Group, y = Value, fill = Subgroup)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean", position = dodge) +
  geom_point(position = dodge) +
  geom_line(color = "red", mapping = aes(group = Pair), position = dodge)
```

The point is to have a bar chart with groups and subgroups (success), with the individual dots plotted centered above each bar (success), and with lines connecting pairwise samples (fail). The result is not too far off, but apparently, instead of making the points avoid each other and then drawing the lines, `ggplot2` draws the vertical lines and then makes *them* avoid each other.

Actual:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be easier to facet by `Group` and forgo position adjustments entirely. The below also futzes with labels, panel spacing, etc to mimic the appearance of your original plot as much as possible.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Subgroup, y = Value, fill = Subgroup)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean", width = 1) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = Pair), color = "red", ) +
  facet_wrap(vars(Group), scales = "free_x", strip.position = "bottom") +
  labs(x = "Group") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    panel.spacing = unit(0, units = "line")
  )
```

[image]