# How to connect geom_point and geom_line when using jittered position for points using facet_wrap in a graph with 2 subgroups?

Tags: r, facet-wrap, geom-point

I had a similar problem as [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71385587/how-to-draw-lines-connecting-pair-wise-points-above-dodging-bars-in-r/) , and the solution almost worked for my data, but I'm having problems to connect the points to the lines when I add jitter. I addeded jitter to the geom_point (position = "jitter") component as my individual points were overlapping in the bars, but now my individual lines are not connecting to the points. Does anyone have any suggestion on how to approach the problem? I already tried to create jitter in the dataframe values, but it didn't work either.

I tried the code below expecting to have the individual points connected to the lines, but it didn't work.

I also tried adding an interaction in x, but it also didn't work.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
  Subgroup = c("A.1", "A.2", "A.1", "A.2", "B.1", "B.2"),
  Value = c(10, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12),
  Pair = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Subgroup, y = Value, fill = Subgroup)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean", width = 1) +
  geom_point(position="jitter") +
  geom_line(aes(group = Pair), color = "red", ) +
  facet_wrap(vars(Group), scales = "free_x", strip.position = "bottom") +
  labs(x = "Group") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    panel.spacing = unit(0, units = "line")
  )
```

Edit = worked when implementing position = position_jitter(seed = 1) in both geom_line and geom_point. But unfortunately for my data it still don't work.

My dataframe:

```
tdcs_cer <- as.data.frame(structure(list(Subject = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 17, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 
37, 37, 37, 37, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 45, 45, 45, 
45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 53, 
53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 
57, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 
65, 65, 65, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 81, 81, 81, 81, 
81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89), Group = c("cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", 
"cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum", "cerebellum"
), Music = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), StimType = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Sham", "Anodal", "Cathodal"
), class = "factor"), condition = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L), levels = c("Strong Beat", "Weak Beat", 
"Non-Beat"), class = "factor"), TrialPassnum = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), n = c(3, 8, 3, 1, 10, 20, 1, 3, 2, 3, 10, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 
9, 1, 1, 10, 3, 3, 12, 2, 4, 15, 4, 9, 18, 6, 4, 11, 4, 6, 14, 
3, 2, 7, 1, 1, 3, 2, 20, 7, 20, 6, 12, 1, 5, 11, 4, 7, 13, 1, 
6, 16, 1, 5, 18, 3, 3, 14, 4, 1, 1, 20, 20, 20, 20, 2, 20, 20, 
2, 7, 3, 2, 11, 2, 5, 12, 2, 20, 6, 1, 20, 4, 20, 20, 4, 1, 20, 
2, 1, 20, 3, 1, 20, 20, 20, 1, 5, 2, 1, 9, 1, 1, 4, 1, 9, 19, 
6, 2, 18, 1, 3, 14, 6, 1, 20, 20, 1, 5, 20, 2, 10, 20, 2, 13, 
1, 2, 11, 2, 4, 15, 1, 7, 16, 5, 1, 8, 2, 6, 15, 7, 4, 14, 4, 
4, 15, 2, 3, 12, 2, 1, 7, 1, 4, 14, 1, 1, 9, 2, 6, 4, 1, 20, 
2, 20, 20, 20, 20), PropCorr = c(15, 40, 15, 5, 50, 0, 5, 15, 
10, 15, 50, 10, 10, 20, 5, 10, 45, 5, 5, 50, 15, 15, 60, 10, 
20, 75, 20, 45, 90, 30, 20, 55, 20, 30, 70, 15, 10, 35, 5, 5, 
15, 10, 0, 35, 0, 30, 60, 5, 25, 55, 20, 35, 65, 5, 30, 80, 5, 
25, 90, 15, 15, 70, 20, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 10, 35, 15, 
10, 55, 10, 25, 60, 10, 0, 30, 5, 0, 20, 0, 0, 20, 5, 0, 10, 
5, 0, 15, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 25, 10, 5, 45, 5, 5, 20, 5, 45, 95, 
30, 10, 90, 5, 15, 70, 30, 5, 0, 0, 5, 25, 0, 10, 50, 0, 10, 
65, 5, 10, 55, 10, 20, 75, 5, 35, 80, 25, 5, 40, 10, 30, 75, 
35, 20, 70, 20, 20, 75, 10, 15, 60, 10, 5, 35, 5, 20, 70, 5, 
5, 45, 10, 30, 20, 5, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-171L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

My code for my figure:

```
My_Theme = theme(
  title = element_text(size = 15),
  axis.title.x = element_blank(),
  axis.text.x = element_blank(),
  axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16),
  axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),
  strip.text.y = element_blank(),
  strip.text = element_text(size=15),
  strip.background = element_blank(),
  strip.placement = "outside",
  axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
  axis.line.x = element_line(linetype="solid"),
  legend.text = element_text(size = 13))
    

cer_plot <- ggplot(tdcs_cer, aes(x=StimType, y = PropCorr, fill = StimType)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean", width = 0.6, size=0.5, alpha=0.9) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width=0.3, size = 0.5, alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_point(aes(x=StimType,y=PropCorr, color=StimType), size=2.5,position = position_jitter(seed = 1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("lightgrey", "pink", 'cyan'))+
  geom_line(aes(group = Subject), color = "antiquewhite3", size=0.6, alpha=0.5, position = position_jitter(seed = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(condition), scales = "free_x", strip.position = "bottom") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Sham" = "darkgrey",
                               "Anodal" = "brown1",
                               "Cathodal" = "blue"))+
  ggtitle("Right Cerebellum") +
  labs(x = "", y = "Percent Correct")+
  theme_classic()+
  My_Theme
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `position_jitter` in `geom_line` too and set the same random seed via the `seed=` argument:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Subgroup, y = Value, fill = Subgroup)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean", width = 1) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(seed = 1)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Pair),
    color = "red",
    position = position_jitter(seed = 1)
  ) +
  facet_wrap(vars(Group),
    scales = "free_x",
    strip.position = "bottom"
  ) +
  labs(x = "Group") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    panel.spacing = unit(0, units = "line")
  )
```

[image]

**EDIT** The issue with your real data and code is that the data for the `geom_point` and the `geom_line` are in a different order (Unfortunately I have no clue why). As a result the jittered points /lines will not align. The only option I have figured out to fix that is to manually jitter `StimType` and `PropCorr` outside of `ggplot` and to use the jittered values for both layers.

```
library(ggplot2)

tdcs_cer$StimType1 <- jitter(
  as.numeric(factor(tdcs_cer$StimType)),
  amount = .45
)

tdcs_cer$PropCorr1 <- jitter(
  tdcs_cer$PropCorr,
  amount = .45
)

ggplot(tdcs_cer, aes(x = StimType, y = PropCorr)) +
  geom_bar(
    aes(fill = StimType),
    stat = "summary", fun = "mean",
    width = 0.6, size = 0.5, alpha = 0.9
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar",
    width = 0.3, size = 0.5, alpha = 0.4
  ) +
  geom_point(
    aes(
      x = StimType1,
      y = PropCorr1,
      color = StimType
    ),
    size = 2.5
  ) +
  geom_line(
    aes(
      x = StimType1,
      y = PropCorr1,
      group = Subject
    ),
    color = "antiquewhite3",
    size = 0.6, alpha = 0.5
  ) +
  facet_wrap(vars(condition),
    scales = "free_x",
    strip.position = "bottom"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(
    "Sham" = "darkgrey",
    "Anodal" = "brown1",
    "Cathodal" = "blue"
  )) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("lightgrey", "pink", "cyan")
  ) +
  ggtitle("Right Cerebellum") +
  labs(x = "", y = "Percent Correct") +
  theme_classic() +
  My_Theme
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it works with the example, but not with my data unfortunately! I'll edit my question adding my df and code in case it helps.

Comment: See my edit. Perhaps there is an option using `position_jitter`. But the only fix I could figure out is to manually apply the jitter.

Comment: I see, great, it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @banzecoleco Make sure you also sort the data according to the facet wrap/grid to ensure that the jitter position will match accordingly after you facet the plots. https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3535

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the jitter outside the ggplot function and then reference that object in the position argument. Also, you need to apply the same grouping for all layers that use jittering. The code below works on my end:

```html
jitter <- position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.2, jitter.height = 0)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Subgroup, y = Value, fill = Subgroup)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean", width = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(group = Pair), position=jitter) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Pair), color = "red", position = jitter) +
  #facet_wrap(vars(Group), scales = "free_x", strip.position = "bottom") +
  labs(x = "Group") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    panel.spacing = unit(0, units = "line")
  )
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it also worked with the example, but not with my data, I'll edit my question adding my df.